# C++ literal char* or string variable error "cannot be a literal data member"

Tags: c#, c++-cli, literals

I'm working on a C# project which is dependent on a C++/CLI project.  I'm using a few literal members (which are constants in C#) using types such as `int` or `unsigned short` that my C# project can access as a constant.  I wanted to do the same with strings.  Since it's possible in C#, I attempted to do it in C++...which I then ran into the problem.

```
using namespace System;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    static ref class TestClass
    {
        literal char* TestString = "fish";
    };
}
```

IntelliSense doesn't give me errors, but when this code is built, this error shows up:
"'TestNamespace::TestClass::TestString': cannot be a literal data member"

I've changed char* to const char*, std::string, and pointers to other types of chars.  I've done much digging on the internet about this stuff and understand some of it, but I have no idea why this isn't working.  I've also read about string literals and thought that would help me.  Nice stuff to know, but not necessarily in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in .NET are the `System::String^` data type, so you need to declare it as that type, not `char*`.

```
using namespace System;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    static ref class TestClass
    {
        literal String^ TestString = "fish";
    };
}
```

Now `TestString` will be visible from C# as `TestNamespace.TestClass.TestString`.